# ruby - help need to convert an array to a specific type of array of arrays, duplicating the keys as [key, value] int he list

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to convert and array into a specific type of array of arrays.

array = ["Project", "Publication"]

into

array_of_arrays =[["Project", "Project"], ["Publication", "Publication"] ]

The array is not just limited to size two. Its a growing list , so looking for some function to convert it to array_of_arrays.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: You can format your code by indenting it four spaces or by surrounding it with backticks. Typically, use the former for blocks of code, the latter for isolated bits of code within sentences. Also, if you select your code and click on `{}` it will all be indented four spaces. This is a pure-Ruby question so you should not have the Rails tag.  Lastly, in Ruby we speak of *methods* (OOP-like), not *functions*.

Answer (score 2):

```
def replicate(arr, n)
  arr.map { |e| [e]*n }
end

replicate(["Project", "Publication"], 2)
  #=> [["Project", "Project"], ["Publication", "Publication"]]
replicate(["Project", "Publication"], 3)
  #=> [["Project", "Project", "Project"], ["Publication", "Publication", "Publication"]]
replicate([["ProjectA", "ProjectB"], "Publication"], 2)
  #=> [[["ProjectA", "ProjectB"], ["ProjectA", "ProjectB"]], ["Publication", "Publication"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is something map can handle quite easily.

```
a = ["Project", "Publication"]
a.map{|x| [x,x]}
#=> [["Project", "Project"], ["Publication", "Publication"]]
```

Comment: `a.zip(a)` will do the same thing :)